# Why does Sarai Condensed Font look bad when rendered in Bold in Word but not when printed

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts

### Problem

I am trying to use the font Sarai Condensed in Microsoft Word (Office 365) because I have been instructed to use this font. I was struck by how badly it looked when rendered in Word, especially in bold. However, it looked much better when I tried to print it. When I saved it as a PDF from Word and opened it in Acrobat Reader, it also looked much closer to the printed version. I also tried to open it in Microsoft Teams and in Sharepoint. Below are screenshots of a test document (font size 14) that I have taken with these different methods.

[image: Font comparison]

### Comparison

Clearly, the PDF, Sharepoint and Teams are more pleasing to the eye. But Sharepoint and Teams look different compared to the PDF. After some comparison I think that perhaps Sharepoint and Teams are using the separate bold version of the font, while both Word and the PDF are doing some kind of generic bolding. But there also seems to be something else making the Word version appear ugly. I don't know how to properly describe it, but there seems to be too little space between letters and bad anti-aliasing or something.

### Questions

- What is causing these differences?
- What can I do to improve the appearance of the font in Word?

Comment: Don't know, but the font libraries used for printing and those used for displaying in Word might be different. The characters are just Unicode, etc. until they get sent to something that renders them using a table they get from somewhere (font library) and what's needed to render an image on the screen and on the printer/PDF are not the same. Maybe you need  a different library for that font for Word. Also, there are different formats of fonts. Some are TrueType (TTF), but there are several other standards.